# Access Parent/Owning class variable from composed class?

Tags: c#, composition

Forgive me because I know my wording is terrible. I'll just give an example.

```
public class MainClass{
    public int someVariable;
    public List<HasAClass> cList = new List<HasAClass>();

    addHasAClass(HasAClass c){
        cList.Add(c);
    }

}
public class HasAClass{
    public HasAClass(){
        //Modify someVariable in some way????
    }
}
public class HasASubClass : HasAClass{
    public ComposedClass(){
        //Modify someVariable in some way???
    }
}
```

I having trouble finding the right words for this questions but here is what I am trying to do:
I am creating an aid for an RPG similar to dungeons and dragons. Each character can have a variety of special abilitys which can effect the characters in some way (both negative and positive). I am trying do this with a variety of subclasses which store the pertinent info and get added to the character at varying points in time. What I can't figure out is how to modify the properties of the Character(I called it Main Class in my example) when instances of the HasA class are added to it.

Comment: Do it from the `addHasAClass` function, in `MainClass`.

Comment: @Blorgbeard I couldn't really do it from there. My example is not really complex enough. There are a lot of properties in the main class. Each one of the 40+ HasA class modifies different values, as well as contains other info.

Comment: You need to pass "parent"/"container" object to child/sub-element one... Note that it may be better to ask child object about changes ("eachChild.ModifyArmorRating(ref computedArmorRating)") instead of pushing changes into parent class deepening on your design/needs.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov I think I see where you are going with that, and I think you are right. I'm going to try that. I need to think about which version will be less complicated but I think it will be pushing the changes into the parent class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The **HasAClass** needs a reference to the owning instance, so that it can ask the parent for values and update them when required...

```
public class HasAClass
{
    private MainClass _mainClass;
    public HasAClass(MainClass mainClass)
    {
        _mainClass = mainClass;
        _mainClass.someVaraible = 42;
    }
}
```

You then need to pass the owner reference into the constructor of the **HasAClass** when they are created. If this is not possible at the time of creating the instance then you would instead need to assign it as a property after it has been created. Such as inside the **addHasAClass** method.